# While train the model always getting "Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt"

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am working with one project in python using Tensorflow. But I am very beginner in Tensorflow and OpenCV. Last day I tried to custom objects. But while training I am always getting one status.

"I0725 10:26:31.453798  5176 supervisor.py:1117] Saving checkpoint to path traini
ng/model.ckpt".

I don't know I what exactly happening, Is this error or not?
I already waited around 10 hours. But now also getting this same status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is informative. It's just telling you, that the checkpoint of the model you're training was saved. In case you find the model "getting worse" from that checkpoint, you can cancel the training with the latest best version of the model saved.

Look for some tutorials for how to find out when the model is not getting better. Get familiar with terms like overfitting/overtraining, etc. to understand the process itself.